# How to get mac address of client in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want get mac address of my website visitor in asp.net
how can i do it?

this code get host mac address

```
            ManagementClass objMC = new  ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();

        foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
        {
            if (!(bool)objMO["ipEnabled"])
                continue;

            string a = ((string)objMO["MACAddress"]);
        }
```

Comment: Your only option is to have something running on the client. Ages ago, you would accomplish this using ActiveX :). Today, I don't think it is possible, even using modern-day equivalent techniques, like google NaCl. But then, why would you want the MAC address? It is not a good idea...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot get the MAC of your visitor because MAC addresses do not survive hops across different hosts like IP addresses do. At the most what you could get is the MAC of the switch closest to the server, and even in that case I 'm not sure it is technically possible from ASP.NET.