# get mac address of client machine using asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I tried many solutions but i'm just getting mac address of the server. I need to get mac address of the client machine. Is this possible to get mac address of the client machine?

If not, is this possible to get any other unique id from client machine?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476714/how-to-get-mac-address-of-client-in-asp-net

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: **No**

It is not possible to get the MAC address from the client using JavaScript as this will pose a serious security risk.

The only unique id you will be able to get is the IP address, but this will possibly not be unique as the user's machine might be NATed behind a router.

You could use an ActiveX control on Java applet to get the client machine's MAC address, but this would require installation of the chosen method on the client machine and will never be a fail-safe way of obtaining the MAC address.